# When a user inputs a second string, it executes the first one typed

Tags: java

```
public static int atk = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("DUNGEONS AND DWAGONS");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        help();


        String input = scan.next();

    // when someone types help first it works, but when they type stats after it shows what would happen if someone typed help.     
        while(true){
            if (input.equals("help")){
                help();
                scan.next();

            }else if(input.equals("stats")){
                stats();
                scan.next();
            }
         }
    }
    static void help() {
        System.out.println("type n,s,e,w to move in a direction");
        System.out.println("type stats to see your stats");
        System.out.println("type look and then a direction n,e,s,w see the sights");
        System.out.println("if you wish to see this again type help");

    }

    static void stats(){
        System.out.println("Health " + health);
        System.out.println("Armour " + armour);
        System.out.println("Attack  " + atk);

    }

}
```

// I have tried every thing and if you type anything after the first thig typed it will execute the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Does `input` ever change?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is leading you in the right direction. You are not assigning your scanner reads to the `input` variable after the first time.

Comment: how do i fix that then

Answer (score 5):

Just move scan.next outside of if/else and assign it to input variable like:

```
if (..) {
    help();
} else {
    stats();
}
 input = scan.next();
```

And expect exit so you can come out of while loop and terminate your program gracefully.

Comment: @Jacob you can accept the answer if it helped, it will help other users in future who will face the same issue.